# Javafx 2.0 arabic text Incorrect Order

Tags: text, javafx, arabic, javafx-2

I am new in JavaFx 2.0, and I am facing a problem with arabic text where javafx print it in incorrect order. I tried to find a solution in internet, but there is no resource about. So, doe any one have an idea how to solve this problem in JavaFx 2.0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Bi-Directional text is not yet supported.

You may want to track and vote for corresponding Feature Request: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17411

Answer (score 7):

There is a right-to-left support in JDK8 earl access. There a Node has the Method `setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`