# how to use right to left in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javafx 2.0 arabic text Incorrect Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910890/javafx-2-0-arabic-text-incorrect-order)

I use setcomponentorientation method for right to left in swing java.

how to use right to left in javafx for arabic language?
how to use arabic font in javafx?